# Why are these 2 simple lines of code in R not working?

Tags: r, plot

```
medals <- c(rep("United States",121), rep("China",70),rep("Great Britain",67), rep("Russia",56), rep("Germany",42), rep("France",42), rep("Japan",41 ), rep("Australia",29), rep("Italy",28), rep("Canada",22))    
barplot(medals, names.arg=c("USA", "CHN", "GBR", "RUS", "GER","FRA","JPN","AUS","ITA","CAN"), main = "Top 10 Medal Winning Countries from the Rio 2016 Olympics", xlab = "Countries", ylab="Total Medals Won", cex.names=0.95)
```

These two lines of code are giving this error "Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

I'm trying to use R the first time

Comment: It's not really necessary to repeat each; just make a table of counts: `with(as.data.frame(table(medals)), barplot(Freq, names.arg = medals))` or with ggplot: `ggplot(as.data.frame(table(medals)), aes(medals, Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: Please describe what you're trying to achieve as well

Comment: Just add `table()` to your code, 2nd row: 
`barplot(table(medals), names.arg=c("USA", "CHN", "GBR", "RUS", "GER","FRA","JPN","AUS","ITA","CAN"), main = "Top 10 Medal Winning Countries from the Rio 2016 Olympics", xlab = "Countries", ylab="Total Medals Won", cex.names=0.95)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `barplot` expects a numerical `height` argument, not a list of characters.

try

```
plot(factor(medals))
```

That gets you a barplot (once you have a factor it defaults to a barplot and supplies the right information). You should be able to manipulate further from there.

In fact if you investigate what `plot.factor` does (`graphics:::plot.factor`), it calls `barplot(table(x),...`  (where `x` is the factor argument to `plot.factor`) - that's another possible avenue.

You should investigate/learn about factors, they're an important part of how R deals with categorical variables. See `?factor`.

If you want to call `barplot` directly, you supply it with relative bar heights (i.e. the counts). One way to do that would be

```
barplot(summary(factor(medals)))
```

(or by using `table` rather than `summary` as mentioned earlier), and then you can set the names as you were trying to before